Angular 13 while deploying in Jenkins, the platform team is saying that AEM publishers are crashing
I have upgraded my angular version from angular 11 to angular 13. While I'm deploying on Jenkins my deployment got successful but post after that Adobe team is saying that AEM publishers are breaking down because of my application is generating huge logs they are saying.
Do we need commit . angular folder which got generated for angular 13 m

What is an AEM? Need more information.

AEM in this case is Adobe Experience Manager. But the solution sounds simple enough, throttle the logs - either in Angular, if Angular is directly writing logs to the file system, set it to write out critical errors only. And if it's generating AEM publish instance logs, have the AEM team turn off logging on the relevant classes.
